# Splitting list elements after many delimiters

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list

I would like to cut the list elements after a chosen delimiters(many at once): '-', ',' and ':'

I have an example list:

```py
list_1 = ['some text – some another', 'some text, some another', 'some text: some another']
```

I'd like to cut the list elements(strings in that case) so that it will return the following output:

```py
splitted_list = ['some text', 'some text', 'some text']
```

I already tried with split() but it only takes 1 delimiter at a time:

```py
splited_list = [i.split(',', 1)[0] for i in list_1]
```

---

I would prefer something which is more understandable for me and where I could decide which delimiter to use. For example, I don't want to cut string after `-` but after `-`.

List of delimiters:

`:`  , `-` , `,`

Note that `-` has space before and after, `:`  only after, just like `,` .

Comment: `splited_list = [i.split(',', 1)[0].split('-', 1)[0].split(':', 1)[0] for i in list_1]` to split new "result" again or just replace 2 delims into third and split with it: `splited_list = [i.replace('-',',').replace(':',',').split(',', 1)[0] for i in list_1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this regex in `re.sub` and replace it with an empty string:

```
\s*[^\w\s].*
```

This will match 0 or more whitespace followed by a character that is not a whitespace and not a word character and anything afterwards.

```sh
import re

list_1 = ['some text – some another', 'some text, some another', 'some text: some another']
delims = [',', ':', ' –']
delimre = '(' + '|'.join(delims) + r')\s.*'
splited_list = [re.sub(delimre, '', i) for i in list_1]

print (splited_list)
```

**Output:**

```
['some text', 'some text', 'some text']
```

Comment: Yes, your solution working perfectly fine, although I would prefer something which is more understandable for me and where I could decide which delimiter to use. For example, I don't want to cut string after '-' but after ' - '. Don't get me wrong - your code is very OK - thanks for that - I just look for a more manageable example.

Comment: Please specify which delimiters you want to include and answer can be tweaked easily.

Comment: ': ' , ' - ' , ', ' Note that ' - ' has space before and after, ': ' only after, just like ', '. That's why I needed more manageable code where I could simply add them. Thank you.

Comment: ok check my updated answer now

Comment: anubhava any chance you could shortly explain what this code does - delimre = '(' + '|'.join(delims) + r')\s.*'

Comment: Please print `delimre` right after this line to see the regex string it is forming. `'|'.join(delims)` joins each element of `delims` array using `|` as delimiter.